# How to update a d3 grouped barchart with new data by using join in v6

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

So I am trying to update a grouped bar chart with new data. The user has a drop-down to select a branch and see the statistic on the number of calls and type.
Right now when I select one of the options the chart is drawn but the following error is thrown in the log. When I then select another option the new data is drawn on top of the already drawn graph and the error is thrown again

```
Uncaught Error: invalid merge
    at Selection$1.selection_merge [as merge] (d3.v6.js:1690)
    at Selection$1.selection_join [as join] (d3.v6.js:1686)
    at draw (Charts:236)
    at Object.success (Charts:126)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

draw (Charts:236) is the join statment in my code

Here is an example of the input data I have, but the user will of course have the option to choose the dates they want the information from.

```
var A = [{"Date":"2021-02-01","CallTypeOne":69,"CallTypeTwo":67,"CallTypeThree":2,"CallTypeFour":0},{"Date":"2021-02-02","CallTypeOne":69,"CallTypeTwo":69,"CallTypeThree":0,"CallTypeFour":0}]

var B = [{"Date":"2021-02-01","CallTypeOne":116,"CallTypeTwo":114,"CallTypeThree":2,"CallTypeFour":0},{"Date":"2021-02-02","CallTypeOne":43,"CallTypeTwo":40,"CallTypeThree":1,"CallTypeFour":2},{"Date":"2021-02-03","CallTypeOne":270,"CallTypeTwo":221,"CallTypeThree":26,"CallTypeFour":23}]
```

And here is my code for creating the charts

```
var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 60, left: 40 },
        width = 1060 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x0 = d3.scaleBand()
        .rangeRound([0, width])
        .padding(0.2)


    var x1 = d3.scaleBand();

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .range(["#4472c4", "#ed7d31", "#a5a5a5", "#ffc000", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x0);

    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
        .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

    var svg = d3.select("#ChartInfo").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    function draw(dataInput) {
        console.log(dataInput);
        var data = JSON.parse(dataInput)
        console.log(data);

        var keys = Object.keys(data[0]).slice(1);

        x0.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.Date; }));
        x1.domain(keys).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d3.max(keys, function (key) { return d[key]; }); })]).nice();

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis)
            .selectAll("text")
            .style("text-anchor", "start")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(45)");

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Population");

        var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "state")
            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.Date) + ",0)"; });

        state.selectAll("rect")
            .data(function (d) {
                return keys.map(function (key) {
                    return { key: key, value: d[key] };
                });
            })
            .join(
            function (enter) {
                return enter
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
                    .attr("x", function (d) { return x1(d.key); })
                    .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.value); })
                    .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.value); })
                    .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.key); })
            },
            function (update) {
                return update
                    .transition()
                    .duration(750)
                    .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
                    .attr("x", function (d) { return x1(d.key); })
                    .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.value); })
                    .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.value); })
                    .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.key); })
            },
            function (exit) {
                return exit
                    .remove()
            });

        var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
            .data(keys)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "legend")
            .attr("transform", function (d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

        legend.append("rect")
            .attr("x", width - 18)
            .attr("width", 18)
            .attr("height", 18)
            .style("fill", color);

        legend.append("text")
            .attr("x", width - 24)
            .attr("y", 9)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text(function (d) { return d; });
    }
```

Here is a picture of what the chart looks like after I have selected both options

[image: Example of chart where graphs are drawn on top off each other]

EDIT:
I am running it in Razor Pages but as far as I can see it's a problem with my ability to do the whole join, merge, exit correctly :)

Link to fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/r40vLscd/

Comment: Your code sample seems to be incomplete. Can you provide a working snippet or fiddle?

Comment: Sorry for my slow response, I have added a fiddle with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have found multiple errors in your code:

1. New X Axis and Y Axis are created each time you draw another chart. The old ones should be removed before
2. Merge does not work properly. Instead, I redraw rectangles for each group.

See the fixed chart in the snippet:

```js
const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 60, left: 40 };
const width = 1060 - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
const x0 = d3.scaleBand()
  .rangeRound([0, width])
  .padding(0.2)
    
    
const x1 = d3.scaleBand();
    
const y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);
    
const color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["#4472c4", "#ed7d31", "#a5a5a5", "#ffc000", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);
    
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x0);
    
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));
    
const svg = d3.select("#ChartInfo")
    .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
function draw(data) {
    const keys = Object.keys(data[0]).slice(1);
    
    x0.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.Date; }));
  x1.domain(keys).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { 
    return d3.max(keys, function (key) { 
        return d[key]; 
    }); 
  })])
  .nice();
  
  svg.selectAll(".x_axis,.y_axis").remove();
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x_axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(45)");
    
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y_axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Population");
    
  const state = svg.selectAll(".state")
    .data(data, d => d.Date);
                
  const newState = state.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "state");
              
  newState.merge(state)  
    .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.Date) + ",0)"; })
    .each(function(d) {
        const g = d3.select(this);
      g.selectAll('rect').remove();
            Object.keys(d)
        .filter(key => key !== 'Date')
        .forEach(key => {
            g.append("rect")
            .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
            .attr("x", x1(key))
            .attr("y", y(d[key]))
            .attr("height", height - y(d[key]))
            .style("fill", color(key))
          });
    });
            
    state.exit().remove();    
     
            var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
                .data(keys)
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "legend")
                .attr("transform", function (d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });
    
            legend.append("rect")
                .attr("x", width - 18)
                .attr("width", 18)
                .attr("height", 18)
                .style("fill", color);
    
            legend.append("text")
                .attr("x", width - 24)
                .attr("y", 9)
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text(function (d) { return d; });
        
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-2">
            <div class="container-fluid p-3 my-3">
                <h1>Select Queue</h1>
                <button onclick="ChartOne()" id="myButton">ChartOne</button>
                <button onclick="ChartTwo()" id="myButtonTwo">ChartTwo</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="container-fluid p-3 my-3">
                <h1>Charts</h1>
                <p>Page to test charts.</p>
    
                <h2>Chart</h2>
                <div id="ChartInfo">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ChartOne() {
            testAjax(function (output) {
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function testAjax() {
            var A = [{"Date":"2021-02-01","CallTypeOne":116,"CallTypeTwo":114,"CallTypeThree":2,"CallTypeFour":0},{"Date":"2021-02-02","CallTypeOne":43,"CallTypeTwo":40,"CallTypeThree":1,"CallTypeFour":2},{"Date":"2021-02-03","CallTypeOne":270,"CallTypeTwo":221,"CallTypeThree":26,"CallTypeFour":23}];
            draw(A);
    
        }
    </script>
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ChartTwo() {
            testTwoAjax(function (output) {
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function testTwoAjax() {
            var A =[{"Date":"2021-02-01","CallTypeOne":69,"CallTypeTwo":67,"CallTypeThree":2,"CallTypeFour":0},{"Date":"2021-02-02","CallTypeOne":69,"CallTypeTwo":69,"CallTypeThree":0,"CallTypeFour":0}];
            draw(A);
    
        }
    </script>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```